# SQL - reference IN member into SELECT

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to get results like:

```
12355/12385
12355/12386
12355/12052
12220/12385
etc.
```

...out of statement like:

```
SELECT ComRels.ParentID 
FROM ComRels
WHERE ComRels.ID IN (SELECT ID FROM Components WHERE Key = 'x2145')
```

...where the IN part for an example above returns {12355,1220} and whole ParentID column, based on the two values, returns {12385, 12386, 12052, 12385} (yes, 12385 is there twice for two different assemblies).

In another words, I would like to know and pass into result set, **which result belongs to which condition** in the WHERE clause.

This is only an example based on a longer code, which works with up-to 5 levels of assemblies and uses a temp table to store results. So the result may also look like "13886/13756/12355/12052", but this is not related to the principle I query.

Is this possible, or do I have to redesign the SQL code completely?

Comment: So you need to select ID + '/' + ParentID (+convert the ints to varchar)?

Comment: Yes, kind-of (if simplified). I should have written, that I tried CONCAT(ParentID,'/', TMP.ID) where TMP is alias for the sub query table in WHERE clause. But I get an error "The multi-part identifier "TMP.ID" could not be bound". It seems this is not permitted/possible due to SQL logic...

Comment: I think sample data as well as desired results would clarify what you are doing.

Comment: I'm afraid the system I make a form/view for is a 3rd party software and I avoid making direct referencing to avoid any possible troubles with non-disclosure agreement. I tried to provide fabricated examples and can improve them, though.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to include duplicate results from intersection with Components table, then you should redesign your query and use `INNER JOIN` instead of `IN` sub-select.

To combine result as you have described, use convert both values into `VARCHAR` and concatenate results.

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(20), cr.ID) + '/'+ CONVERT(varchar(20), cr.ParentID)
FROM ComRels cr
INNER JOIN Components c ON cr.ID=c.ID AND c.Key= 'x2145'
```

Comment: Tank you, I will investigate this answer. I tried this approach on different ocasion in past and found some items not appearing in a result set, which according to community here, is a bug... But I will try again and see and mark the answer consequently.